# VBScript Regex Replace when numbers are enclosed by quotation marks

Tags: regex, vbscript

Using Regex in VBScript I need to replace commas that are in decimals enclosed by quotation marks chr(34) with dots

```
Input
20170927,Ford,,"6025,00",,"0,00",1,T
20170928,"Fiat, Opel",,"13587,17","13587,17",2,N

Output
20170927,Ford,,"6025.00",,"0.00",1,T
20170928,"Fiat, Opel",,"13587.17","13587.17",2,N
```

I've tried the below code but didn't work.

```
Dim oRE,text
Set oRE = New RegExp
oRE.Global = True
oRE.Pattern = chr(34)+[0-9],[0-9]+chr(34)
oRE.Replace(text, Replace(text,",","."))
```

Many thanks.

Comment: `("\d+),(\d+")` replace with `$1.$2`. Also, I believe you need to put your regex in quotes (which means you'll have to escape them in the regex).

Comment: I've replaced quotation marks with XXX to avoind problems in Pattern and used your suggestion but didn't work: Dim oRE, text
Set oRE = New RegExp
oRE.Global = True
oRE.Pattern = chr(34)
text=oRE.Replace(text, "XXX")
oRE.Pattern = "(XXX\d+),(\d+XXX)"
oRE.Replace(text, "$1.$2")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this Code below:

**Code:**

```
strTest = "20170928,""Fiat, Opel"",,""13587,17"",""13587,17"",2,N"    'Store the text to be tested in this variable
Set re = New RegExp
re.Global=True
re.Pattern = "(""\d*),(\d+"")"
Set objMatches = re.Execute(strTest)

For Each match In objMatches
    strTest = Replace(strTest,match.Value,match.Submatches.Item(0)&"."&match.Submatches.Item(1))
Next

MsgBox strTest
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Regex used:**

```
("\d*),(\d+")
```

[Click here for Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/r1nbW1/2)

**Regex Explanation:**

- `("\d*)` - matches a `"` followed by 0+ occurrences of a digit. Parenthesis captures this whole part in group 1.
- `,` - matches `,` literally
- `(\d+")` - matches 1+ occurrences of a digit followed by `"`. Parenthesis captures this whole part in group 2.

Answer (score 3):

## Part of the problem

In your regex

```
oRE.Pattern = chr(34)+[0-9],[0-9]+chr(34)
                     ^
```

[image]

The `+` symbol after the `chr(34)` instructs the Regex engine to require one or more quotes

I think the `+` symbol should be moved to after the character set.

```
oRE.Pattern = chr(34)[0-9]+,[0-9]+chr(34)
                          ^
```

## Proposed solution

You should capture the open/close quote internal digits into capture groups which are then used in the replacement.

Regex `("[0-9]+),([0-9]+")`

Replace with: `$1.$2`

See this [Live Demo](https://regex101.com/r/608FMo/1)

Sample input text:

```
20170927,Ford,,"6025,00",,"0,00",1,T
20170928,"Fiat, Opel",,"13587,17","13587,17",2,N
```

Sample after replacement

```
20170927,Ford,,"6025.00",,"0.00",1,T
20170928,"Fiat, Opel",,"13587.17","13587.17",2,N
```

## Sample VB code

Note that the internal double quotes are doubled so that the string is constructed correctly.

**VB Script**

```
strTest = "20170927,Ford,,""6025.00"",,""0.00"",1,T" & vbCrLf & "20170928,""Fiat, Opel"",,""13587,17"",""13587,17"",2,N"    
Set re = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
re.Global = True
re.Pattern = "(""\d*),(\d+"")"

strTest = re.Replace(strTest, "$1.$2")
```

**VB.net**

```
Dim sourcestring as String = "replace with your source string"
Dim replacementstring as String = "$1.$2"
Dim matchpattern as String = "(""[0-9]+),([0-9]+"")"
Console.Writeline(regex.Replace(sourcestring,matchpattern,replacementstring))
```

## Regex Explanation

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    "                        '"'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-9]+                   any character of: '0' to '9' (1 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ,                        ','
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-9]+                   any character of: '0' to '9' (1 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    "                        '"'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \2
```

Comment: Good explanation but please refrain from using VB on VBScript questions it will just confuse those not familiar with the differences *(i.e. typeless versus strongly typed)*.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good point, I forgot that like Java and Javascript, both VB and VBScript are different. I've updated the answer to include both.